# Turn off HDMI output after receiving HTTP GET request

Tags: display

I'm building a security camera setup, and am displaying the camera feeds (RTSP streams) using a Raspberry Pi. I only want the display to be active when a motion event is triggered - this is handled by a server, which sends a HTTP request whenever an event is detected.

I'm really new to working with Pis. How can I set it up (presumably using a web server) so that whenever a GET request comes in, a script is executed? I'd write the script so that the display is turned on, and after a minute is turned off again.

Comment: The question is not specific to the Pi. What you are asking is how to run a script on a web request on Linux. Googling that will turn up useful information.

Comment: At first, you should find out how to turn off the HDMI and then find the script on other communities like Unix SE.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just installing Apache with PHP and executing a shell script whenever the page was accessed. Display output can be controlled using vcgencmd.